the value of the finite sum $F(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{z=1}^nq(z/(n+1))$ for the Pareto quantile function $q$
Let $q:(0,1)\mapsto\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ be the quantile function associated to the Pareto distribution, $q(x)=a(1-x)^{-1/b}$. I am interested in the value of $F(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{z=1}^n q(z/(n+1))$. Of course, $F(n)\rightarrow\int_0^1q(x)dx$ as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. When I attempt to use a computer algebra system, such as Mathematica, to compute the result, it yields solutions in terms of the Hurwitz-Zeta function that does not evaluate to finite real numbers. Does anyone know how to compute the value of the sum $F(n)$ in a closed-form manner?
